# Can cypress click on an element it cannot see?

Tags: cypress

I have an webpage (unfortunately I can't share as it's internal test one for my company) but essentially we have an item appear that has an "Accept" button for cookies, unfortunately I believe it's CSS so Cypress can't see the element if I use the selector and nor it cannot see the accept button.

Is there anyway around this?

I have tried using tab to get down to the element but as Cypress can't see the element it cannot click on it to initiate that.

Comment: Can you add the HTML for the relevant button? As you've described it, the question and your attempts aren't clear to me.

Comment: You can scrub your tests/html and share them.

Comment: Sure, it's here: 

<button title="Accept" class="message-component message-button no-children focusable teg-button sp_choice_type_11" style="padding: 12px 50px; margin: 0px; border-width: 2px; border-color: rgb(60, 79, 175); border-radius: 5px; border-style: solid; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; width: auto; background: rgb(60, 79, 175);">Accept</button>

Answer (score 1):

You can add `force: true` with your click command for this.

```js
cy.get('selector').click({force: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to select what the user can see, which is the "Accept" text on the button.

If it's visible on the page, Cypress can ***eventually*** find it but you have to design the command to retry which means adding some sort of `.should()` assertion on the element.

```js
cy.contains("Accept")
  .should('be.visible')   // in case there's a delay in displaying the button
  .click()
```